# ffmpeg command not found but its installed on server

Tags: linux, command-line, video, ffmpeg, git

I was trying to update ffmpeg, after searching a lot on this topic i decided to uninstall the old one and install new version of ffmpeg i-e; ffmpeg 2.6.3
i installed new version using this [link](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Centos) but i was facing problem in installing ffmpeg from git when i was trying to use ./configure command it was showing error "./configure no such file or directory", i searched on this issue several hours and finally install ffmpeg from this [link](https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html) and unzip it through "tar" command. In this way i was able to run ./configure command and installed it successfully. But now when i try to check if ffmpeg is installed using command "ffmpeg" its showing

```
-bash: line 232: ffmpeg: command not found
```

and when i try "which ffmpeg" its showing

```
which: no ffmpeg in (/usr/local/jdk/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/root/bin)
```

Please tell me why this happening. Is there something missing in my installation.

Kind Regards

Comment: After `./configure`, was there supposed to be a `make` and a `make install` command? The `./configure` command just begins the process to compile the software. How successful were you in installing the dependencies in the first link (i.e. libx264, etc)?

Comment: it was giving error for x264 link so i use snapshot for that and it got installed sucessfully. x265 was not installed.

Comment: yes i executed commands make and make install only when i installed ffmpeg from second link in the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What linux are you using?  Have you tried doing a search for ffmpeg?

```
updatedb
locate ffmpeg
```

It may not be in the path.

As per comment, I suggest copying /home/virtfs/trvl/usr/bin/ffmpeg to /usr/bin/ffmpeg and this should fix the problem.  And copy /home/virtfs/trvl/usr/local/share/ffmpeg to /usr/local/share/ffmpeg

Comment: i am using centos 6

Comment: yes i searched using whereis ffmpeg but its showing result ffmpeg:

Comment: when i execute "locate ffmpeg" it shows the following result
`/home/virtfs/trvl/usr/bin/ffmpeg
/home/virtfs/trvl/usr/include/ffmpeg
/home/virtfs/trvl/usr/lib64/gpac/gm_ffmpeg_in.so
/home/virtfs/trvl/usr/local/share/ffmpeg
/home/virtfs/trvl/usr/local/share/ffmpeg/examples
/home/virtfs/trvl/usr/local/share/ffmpeg/ffprobe.xsd
/home/virtfs/trvl/usr/local/share/ffmpeg/libvpx-1080p.ffpreset
/home/virtfs/trvl/usr/local/share/ffmpeg/libvpx-1080p50_60.ffpreset
/home/virtfs/trvl/usr/local/share/ffmpeg/libvpx-360p.ffpreset
/home/virtfs/trvl/usr/local/share/ffmpeg/libvpx-720p.ffpreset`

Comment: What is your path?  I'm willing to bet that this /home/virtfs/trvl/usr/bin is not in your path.  You should be able to just copy /home/virtfs/trvl/usr/bin/ffmpeg to /usr/bin/ffmpeg and this should fix the problem.

Comment: yes you are right. i am moving ffmpeg_sources folder to usr/local/bin

Comment: Not sources, just the one bin file.  Did you do make install?  And you should probably copy over /home/virtfs/trvl/usr/local/share/ffmpeg to /usr/local/share/ffmpeg

Comment: you are saying just to move ffmpeg folder ? or what? please explain

Comment: Yes, 2 steps.  1) copy the ffmpeg file in the bin folder to /usr/bin/  2) copy the ffmpeg folder that is inside the share folder to /usr/local/share/

Comment: i am confuse there is no ffmpeg file there is ffmpeg.c and ffmpeg.h which one should  move?

Comment: /home/virtfs/trvl/usr/bin/ffmpeg should be a file.  Am I incorrect?

Comment: there is already a folder ffmpeg in usr/local/share

Comment: is that usr/local/share or /usr/local/share ? Notice the '/' in front.

Comment: yes sorry i forgot "/" its already in share folder. no ffmpeg is just a folder

Comment: You are saying /home/virtfs/trvl/usr/bin/ffmpeg is a folder?  What is in this folder?  "dir /home/virtfs/trvl/usr/bin/ffmpeg "

Comment: yes its a folder.. i am login through root. i dont know why i its showing dir /home/virtfs/trvl/usr/bin/ffmpeg... and this folder is showing just lib x264 and libvpx and ffprobe. no other codecs like libmp3lame etc

Comment: I'm still trying to understand why bin/ffmpeg is a folder.  Can you try running /home/virtfs/trvl/usr/bin/ffmpeg ?  I wonder if (a) there was a problem with the build/install process or (b) this is not the correct install package

Comment: no i am saying /usr/bin/ffmpeg is not a folder, the folder is usr/local/share/ffmpeg/... yes you are right i should reinstall new package. can u please help me with how to remove ffmpeg completely from server

Comment: there is no file ffmpeg in /usr/bin/ffmpeg

Comment: No, /usr/bin/ffmpeg should be a file.  If it is not there, then run "cp /home/virtfs/trvl/usr/bin/ffmpeg /usr/bin/ffmpeg"

Answer (score 3):

**Option 1:**  Add `/home/virtfs/trvl/usr/bin` to your `PATH` variable

**Option 2:** Diagnose why `make install` did not install `ffmpeg` into `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin`

Comment: is there any i can move that to /usr/bin or reinstall to /usr/bin

Comment: please can u tell me how to diagnose "Option 2"

Comment: yes i login  through root so i didnot use "#" as i was already logged in through root

Comment: no `make install` didnot show any error messages

Comment: its strange its showing an error now `yasm/nasm not found or too old. Use --disable-yasm for a crippled build.`

Comment: i have already installed yasm

Comment: I would recommend trying `--disable-yasm` to see if `ffmpeg` will then install correctly.  Afterwards, diagnose why yasm is not installed properly.  Without yasm, ffmpeg will still run just slower.

Comment: i disable yasm and tried it again but its showing this error now `-bash: line 42: ./configure: No such file or directory` aahh i am lost

Answer (score 2):

Go through the guides and diagnose each error as it arises.  For example, "No such file or directory" is vague on its own, but looking at line 42 of ./configure may help.